# Python logic without increasing much time complexity

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to compare my dates without increasing much complexity and lines of code.

My date format is like this : `'24-Jul-2019'` 
start_date format is this:`'2019-12-12'`

But how can I compare such that this line is correct means the date comparison is correct for

```
data['Date'] > start_date and data['Date'] < end_date]
```

Note: I want to compare dates but my due to my dateformat it is showing error.

```
change_difference = [(data['High']- data['Low']) for data in dataset if data['Date'] > start_date and data['Date'] < end_date]
```

Comment: Add the error too!

Comment: Is ``data`` a dataframe? Is ``data['Date']`` a string (such as ``'24-Jul-2019'``) or a datetime (or similar representation)?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi its string

Comment: @Zunayn error is can't comapare as the format's are different.I have also added start_date format please see.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't parse these strings to proper time representations? Python has performant inbuilt tools to do this.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi  can also do that.Please show me using your answer i will upvote for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to compare dates. In your code, you do not seem to parse dates at all, which you can do like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime

datestring_1 = "24-Jul-2019"
datestring_2 = "25-Jul-2019"
format = "%d-%b-%Y"
date_1 = datetime.strptime(datestring_1, format)
date_2 = datetime.strptime(datestring_2, format)
date_1 < date_2  # => True
```

In your applied case: Convert your variables `data['Date']`, `start_date` and `end_date` into datetimes. Once this is done, your comparison should work.

Note: Depending on your locale, you might have to make sure that the format is correct ([see documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior))